# sencha Architect (Touch) - the Store don't read my php file

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have problem to read my php file with the Store. I think that the problem is the base64_encode command in php file.
I Explain it. In my php, I take a path with sql code and after, with this path, I get the real image. After I need to give the results saved in an array, to sencha architect.
This is php Code:

```
require("db.php");
    session_start();
    $filepath='';
    $sql = "SELECT concat('C:/wamp/www/Tecnitalia_Optic/app/webroot/img/',folder) as Path, thumb as FileName FROM frames ";
    $result = array();
    if ($resultdb = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($record = $resultdb->fetch_array()) {
        $filepath = $record['Path'];
        $nomeFile = $record['FileName'];
        $mimetype = pathinfo($nomeFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filedata=filesize($filepath."/".$nomeFile);
        header('Content-Type: '.$mimetype);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nomeFile.'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.sprintf('%d', $filedata));
        header('Expires: 0');
        //readfile($filepath."/".$nomeFile);
        $recordnew = readfile($filepath."/".$nomeFile);
        $result[] = $recordnew;
    }
    $resultdb->close();
    }
    //count total records from table for paging
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as num FROM frames ";
    $total = 0;
    if ($resultdb = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $record = $resultdb->fetch_assoc();
    $total = $record['num'];
    $resultdb->close();
    }
    //send back information to sencha architect touch
    echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => $mysqli->connect_errno == 0,
    "total" => $total,
    "data" => base64_encode($result)
    )); 
    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

after that, in SA I have created a model with one field with type auto. After I have created a Json Store link with the model but the store say me this: MyJsonReader unable to read data. Open in Browser: api/frames.php

This is my sencha architect code:

Model and store

```
Ext.define('ciaopoint2.model.frames', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'mini',
                type: 'auto'
            }
        ]
    }
    });
Ext.define('ciaopoint2.store.Frames', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.frames',
requires: [
    'ciaopoint2.model.frames',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],
config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'ciaopoint2.model.frames',
    storeId: 'Frames',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'api/frames.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
}
});
```

HI Zoltan Thank you for your reply. Can you explain with an example what do you say? I take off the base64_encode command but after what i can do? Inside Architect Touch or in the php file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to base64 encode the result but you need JSON encode to encode your return value recursively (i.e. the data par should also be a json encoded value).

Comment: HI Zoltan Thank you for your reply. Can you explain with an example what do you say? I take off the base64_encode command but after what i can do? Inside Architect Touch or in the php file?

Comment: Now i have just this code: echo json_encode(array( "success" => $mysqli->connect_errno == 0, "total" => $total, "data" => $result )); I take of the base64_encode but Sencha don't read my php

Comment: What do you get now? Just don't see the store loaded? Have you got your server code publicly available somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: Hi Zoltan. I have resolved. The problem was the readfile command in php. The right command is file_get_command. Thank you